# Passing multiple values into sub report parameter SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which shows product details. Some of these products will be Children of Parent products. The children have 3 columns `Parent1` `Parent2` and `Parent3`.

The sub report runs off the same query except has a variable `@ParentCodes`. This is set as `varchar(max)`. I then use a function in the where clause to split the codes which may be passed `ParentCode in (SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.SplitMultiValueParameterString(@ParentCodes, ','))`

If I pass in 2 or 3 codes in a string like `('123', '456')` then the query returns the 2 rows required.

I am struggling to get this to work in SSRS. I have set up both reports and added the `@ParentCodes` parameter to the sub report.

In the main report, I am using an action on a text box to go to the sub report and passing the parameter `@ParentCodes` with the following value expression `=Fields!Parent1.Value & Fields!Parent2.Value & Fields!Parent3.Value`

In the sub report, in the parameter tab in the dataset I have added the `@ParentCodes` parameter and using the expression `=JOIN(Parameters!ParentCodes, ",")`

This is not working as desired, can anyone understand what I am trying to do and propose a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, if you are using direct statements (in that you just dump the raw SQL into the Report Data) then you need to use an `IN`, and SSRS (as much as I hate it) "safely" replaces the variable in the `IN` with an injection of the parameters. In simple terms, take a query like the below:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID IN (@ID);
```

Then you select the parameters, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` in the report. It would inject those and the query would become the below:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4);
```

If you're using a Stored Procedure, however, you need to use a string splitter (such as [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)) to do the work, and make your parameter a `(n)varchar`:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.YourProc @IDs varchar(8000) AS
BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN dbo.DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD(@IDs, ',') DS ON YT.ID = DS.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting the query to do dynamic SQL in the sub report which won't work, but SSRS should do what you need.

Try [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c507d01f-245a-415a-bcbd-3293ba7beed5/array-creation-in-ssrs-expression?forum=sqlreportingservices) with your subreport with some multiple parent codes.

In your where clause in the subreport you should be able to do this:

WHERE parentcode IN (@parentcodes)

You may need to tweak your JOIN expression as per [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c507d01f-245a-415a-bcbd-3293ba7beed5/array-creation-in-ssrs-expression?forum=sqlreportingservices): article but it might just work.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, the subreport accepts a single comma separated string as a parameter and that gets populated from the main report?

If that is the case then your expression

```
=Fields!Parent1.Value & Fields!Parent2.Value & Fields!Parent3.Value
```

is wrong as it does not have any separators so 123 and 456 would be sent as 123456.

You probably need something like

```
=Fields!Parent1.Value & "," & Fields!Parent2.Value & "," & Fields!Parent3.Value
```

The other option would be to just pass in the child product's ID and then get the parent ID's in the subreport's query. You would not need to do any kind of processing to build or split out parameter values this way.

Comment: I have updated the expression to your suggestion, no error message any more, but no data in the sub report. Also if no parent code, the value in the dataset is null. Could this be an issue?

Comment: The parameter value being passed to the sub report for an instance of a child with 2 parents is ```123,456, ```

Comment: You probably need to edit your question and show the dataset query or at least he important bits of it. Also include a sample of a record/row as it would appear in the master report including the child product as I think the whole thing can possibly be simplified